# C - Initializing structs inside a 2D array before returning double pointer from function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d, double-pointer

I'm new to C Programming and want to focus on learning dynamic allocation. As a learning opportunity for me, I'm trying to create a function that returns a double-pointer for a 2D array of structs. I've been referencing tutorials that generally refer to what is mentioned [here in approach #3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/).

I can see that the tutorial assigns integer values no problem, but I'm not sure how that translates with structs.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

const int HEIGHT    = 64;
const int WIDTH     = 96;

struct Tile
{
    char type;
    bool armed;
    struct Tile* up;
    struct Tile* right;
    struct Tile* down;
    struct Tile* left;
};

struct Tile** createTileMap(unsigned int w, unsigned int h)
{
    struct Tile** map = (struct Tile **)malloc(w * sizeof(struct Tile *));

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        map[x] = (struct Tile *)malloc(h * sizeof(struct Tile));
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            map[x][y] = (struct Tile){.type = '_', .armed = false, .up = NULL,
            .right = NULL, .down = NULL, .left = NULL};
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct Tile** map = createTileMap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            printf("    (%d, %d): ", x, y);
            printf("%c", map[x][y].type);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code segfaults, and I'm not too sure why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `createTileMap()` fails to `return`.

Comment: All of that for nothing. Whoops. I was too focused on the allocation algorithm.

Comment: Your compiler should be able to help you with that if you enable warnings.

Comment: note that you don't need the `false`/`NULL` initializers; if there is at least one initializer then any other fields not mentioned are initialized that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185968/eof), I simply forgot to actually *return the address*. Fortunately my other code was fine, though!